# Generate non-intersecting polygons or another way to calculate the sum of a variable around the points

Tags: python, qgis

I have a complex problem that I am trying to solve using QGIS and Python. I tried to break it down for simpler tasks and would very much appreciate your help/advice on how to solve it in a best way. I understand it is too many questions in one but I feel like I need to explain the whole problem to come up with the best solutions for my sub-problems.

Problem: I've built a map of a variable Z in QGIS using interpolation. I also have a set of control points (input as .shp or through lat, lon) distributed on the map of Z. And I also have a .shp file that represents certain Area of Interest (AOI) on the map of Z.

What I am trying to do is to:
 1. calculate the sum of Z within 500 ft radius from control points AND only within the AOI
 2. calculate the sum of Z within 500-1000 ft distance from control points (ring shape around the control points) AND only within the AOI

I know how to calculate the sum of Z within the shape file using v.rast.stats but here is the tricky part: some points can be closer than 500 ft to each other, as a results if I generate polygons around the control points (like a buffer, for example) I may end up with intersecting polygons. And if I apply v.rast.stats for each of these polygons, values of Z in the zone of intersection will be counted several times which is not correct.

I used another software that allowed to populate another discrete variable Y depending on the distance from the point. Y would have values "1" (within 500 ft radius) and "2" (withing 500-1000 ft window). After that it allowed to apply the rule: Z_500 = If (Y=1, sum(Z)) and Z_1000=if (Y=2, sum(Z)) within the AOI.

But with QGIS I am not sure if this is possible. So far the closest I can think of is to generate non-intersecting polygons around my control points. For the points that are closer than 500 ft the boundary shall be in the mid-distance from these points. But I don't know how to realize that in QGIS.

I would appreciate your help/advise on how to solve this problem. Thanks